# How to check if a dictionary is in another dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an objects

```
>>> L[0].f.items()
dict_items([('a', 1)])
>>> a3.f.items()
dict_items([('a', 1), ('c', 3)])
```

I want to test if L[0].f.items() is a subset of a3.f.items(). So I did the following:

```
>>> L[0].f.items() in a3.f.items()
False
```

But I expect that L[0].f.items() is a subset of a3.f.items(). Why it returns False? How can I test if a dictionary items is a subset of another dictionary items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make sets from the lists and see if one set is a subset of another:

```
>>> list1 = [('a', 1), ('c', 3)]
>>> list2 = [('a', 1)]
>>> set(list2).issubset(list1)
True
```

Or, in your case:

```
set(L[0].f.items()).issubset(set(a3.f.items()))
```

Comment: The OP is on Python 3. You don't need to make sets; you can just use `<=`.

Answer (score 6):

`in` tests whether the left operand is an element of the right. Since dict item views are set-like, you want `<=`, which tests whether one is a subset of another:

```
>>> L[0].f.items() <= a3.f.items()
True
```

If you want to do this with lists or other non-set-like iterables, you can build a set out of one and use `issuperset`:

```
>>> more = [1, 2, 3]
>>> less = [1, 2]
>>> set(more).issuperset(less)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if the actual list is in there, not the tuple. Here, you can use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
all(i in a3.f.items() for i in L[0].f.items())
```

Or even set notation:

```
>>> set(L[0].f.items()) & set(a3.f.items())) == set(L[0].f.items())
True # Note that without the bool call this returns set([('a', 1)]), which can
     # be useful if you have more than one sublist tuples.
```

Comment: Instead of `any`, `all` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Likewise, `bool(... & ...)` is not enough if the condition should be true for *all* elements.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 2.7, you have `dict.viewitems()` which will provide you a set-like behaviour. (Oh, you seem to use Py3, as you have `dict_items()` objects as well!)

So you just could use

```
a = dict(a=1)
b = dict(a=1, c=3)
ai = a.viewitems() # items() on 3.x
bi = b.viewitems() # items() on 3.x
ai - bi
# gives a set([])
bi - ai
# gives a set([('c', 3)])
ai & bi
# gives ai
ai | bi
# gives bi
```

As you want to make sure that every element of `a` is as well contained in `b`, you need

```
ai & bi == ai
```

If this is false, there is an element in `a` missing in `b`, "disturbing" the `&` operation.

EDIT: But it is even simpler - just do

```
ai <= bi
```

as you could do on a set as well.